# change body class when element clicked

Tags: jquery

Is there any way of getting a item list on the body class each time a element is clicked?
Im up to this right now :

```
$("#step a").click(function (i) {
    i = i+1;
    $("body").addClass("item" i);
});
```

Comment: what does **getting a item list on the body class** means ?

Comment: You're missing a concatenation `"item" + i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
$("#step a").click(function () {
    i = i+1;
    $('body').removeClass().addClass('item' + i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your click function will be passing the event through your click function. You can't add 1 to this.**

You should be using something like this in your html. The data attribute will store the step number on the anchor for you:

```
<div id="step">
    <a data-step="1">Click me</a>
</div>
```

And some JavaScript to control it:

```
$("#step a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Stop browser jumping to top of the page

    var step = $(this).attr("data-step"); //Get the current step from attribute
    $("body").addClass("item-" + step); //Add this class to the body

});
```